# Installing libqrencode on windows for python

Tags: python, c++, qr-code

I am working on creating QR codes with a Python project, but I need to install [this](http://fukuchi.org/works/qrencode/index.html.en) library for qrencode, and I am not able to install it on Windows. I have tried everything: Cygwin, MinGW, Microsoft VC++, but I'm not able to build this library on Windows. Please  help me out by focusing on the correct way to install it on Windows using Python26.

Using VC++ I am getting [this](https://www.enthought.com/repo/pypi/logs/Windows/amd64/qrencode-1.0.txt) error.

After I do `pip install qrencode`, I get:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -IC:\Python27\include -IC:\Python27\PC /Tcqr_encode.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\qr_encode.obj
qr_encode.c
qr_encode.c(3) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'qrencode.h': No such file           or directory
error: command '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio     9.0\VC\BIN\amd64\cl.exe"' failed with exit status 2
```

If i use MinGW it asks for more and more libraries to install. Please suggest to me the correct way to install qrencode library, or if someone has the build, please share it with me so that I can use it.

Comment: The build script or source archive is probably broken for Windows. `qrencode.h` is in [this](http://fukuchi.org/works/qrencode/qrencode-3.4.3.tar.gz) archive. Have you search on any mailing lists or other forums ? Surely they would have tested this on Windows.

Comment: That library's page says *"If you are trying to compile this library on MS-Windows, cygwin or some kinds of UNIX-like environments is required"*. That same page also refers to [this](http://code.google.com/p/qrencode-win32/) windows port. I'd suggest trying to find an alternative library.

Comment: i tried using MinGW but it keeps on asking for other libs http://www.gaia-gis.it/spatialite-3.0.0-BETA/mingw_how_to.html#pkg-config ...  aks for pkg-config then asks for sdl lib then asks for libpng which depends on zlib and process goes on and on ....